Problems with branch-n-price implementation
I am currently trying to solve my Column Generation Heuristic with a branch-n-price approach. I want to solve the whole thing with Gurobi. I know that BnP is currently not supported there, but I'm trying to do it using independent branching implementation etc. I am currently proceeding as follows.

I start at the root node, iteratively solve the RMP and add columns as long as they have negative reduced costs.
If no more are found, I look at the solution of the last RMP solution and find the most-fractional $\tilde{\lambda}_r$ variable. Here, $\lambda_r$ is an integer variable that specifies how often schedule $r$ should occur in the solution. (It should be noted here that I have homogeneous workers and therefore have a single subproblem to solve). 3) Based on the variable found, I then branch to 1) ${\lambda}_r\leq \left\lfloor \tilde{\lambda}_r \right\rfloor$ and 2) 1) $\lambda_r\geq \left\lceil \tilde{\lambda}_r \right\rceil$ . To do this, I copy the model from the root node (i.e. keep all previous columns) and add the new constraint.
Now I perform column generation again in each child node to generate new columns.
Now to my problem. Strangely enough, I find new columns in every instance I have tested so far (neither in the right nor in the left first child node) and thus one branch is always the same as the IP solution of the root node, the other is always worse. Now I am wondering how there can be improvement in the solution? Am I doing something wrong?


When you branch on the master variable $\lambda_r$, you are adding a (one-variable) constraint to the master, and you need to modify the subproblem at each node to reflect the branching decisions.
See the "Branching on the master variables" section in Chapter 7 of https://www.researchgate.net/publication/381918232_Branch-and-Price, which includes the following warning on page 465:

this is not a good idea in general.

